# Ajax posting null object to the mvc controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass an object to the MVC controller, but at controller, I get null values to the object which I passed through the ajax.

I am able to see that my object is having some data in the view, but not able to bind them to the controller.

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddImage(ImageModel imageModel)
        {
            UploadRepo.saveImage(imageModel);
            return null;
        }
```

Model

```
namespace Fileupload.Models
{
    public class ImageModel
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ImageData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Javscript Code

```
        var url = input.value;
        var imageData = '';
        var finalUrL = '';
        console.log(input.files[0])
        var ext = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        if (input.files && input.files[0] && (ext == "gif" || ext == "png" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg")) {
            finalUrL = await readAsDataURL(input.files[0])
            imageData = finalUrL.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, '').trim()
            var obj = {
                Id: 1,
                ImageData: imageData
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Upload/AddImage',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),

                contentType: "application/json;",
                success: function (data) {
                    //successMessage();
                    $("form")[0].reset();
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log("textstatus", textStatus, xhr)
                    // errorMessage();-
                }
            });
            console.log("imagedata", myobj);
        } else {
            $('#img').attr('src', '/assets/no_preview.png');
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you getting "over the wire"? You can see in F12 browser screen in network tab

Comment: No, I am not  @Gandalf

Comment: In network tab, I can see request payload is a legit object

Comment: I assume by "legit object" you mean JSON string that *looks* like what you expect. Yet controller action is still null, right? So, it is **not** legit. You can replace parameter from ImageModel to `FormCollection` and then explicitly convert to `ImageModel` and see what kind of error you will get

Answer (score 0):

Attachment file in ASP.NET MVC must be of **HttpPostedFileBase** type. So, change your image data property  as follow i.e.

```
public HttpPostedFileBase ImageData { get; set; }
```

then in your **[HttpPost]** method do following to get data from the uploaded file i.e.

```
// Upload File data.
byte[] fileByteData = new byte[model.ImageData.InputStream.Length];
model.ImageData.InputStream.Read(fileByteData, 0, fileByteData.Length);
string fileContentType = model.ImageData.ContentType;
```